# Console.KeyAvailable isn't being triggered

Tags: c#, console

I am wanting to detect if any key is being pressed but as far as I can tell the if statement isn't being triggered otherwise the program would shut down due to `Enviroment.Exit(0)`.

```
public static int GameLoop()
        {
            while(true)
            {
                if(Console.KeyAvailable == true)
                {
                    Environment.Exit(0); //test to see if being used
                    Player.KeyPressed = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
                    Player.Movement();
                }
                Console.Clear();
                Console.SetCursorPosition(playerX, playerY);
                Console.Write(playerDirection);

                input = (char)Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
```

`GameLoop()` is being called because `Console.WriteLine("working")` is being executed. Any Ideas as to why `Console.KeyAvailable == true` isn't being met on key press? Thanks!

[Console.KeyAvailable MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.keyavailable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: works for me.. a simple console app with the while true if console.keyavailable exit.. works perfectly

Comment: Is your game a console game?

Comment: That should work if it's actually a console application.

Comment: yeah its a console application.. weird.. any ideas?

Comment: Requesting downvoters constructive criticism since all my posts seems to incur downvotes and am looking to improve

Comment: since we can't see more code, i assume that you execute `Console.ReadKey()` already on another place of your code? Because as the others said, your code is working if only the while(true) loop is written in a console application.

Comment: Can confirm the code is working for me in a new console app solution

Comment: will edit op for full ugly code. embarrassing...

Comment: @Trr1ppy I think your question is fine. Its hard to get up votes (or even no down votes) on a question unless its about some new language feature or just a really good question that makes people think.

Comment: @Blake So discouraging as a new programmer eager to learn, oh well

Comment: You are calling ReadKey() inside the loop.  The odds that you can be quick enough to press a key between the ReadKey() and the KeyAvailable call are miniscule.

Comment: It just clicked in my head, a key isn't available if its been read, feel free to post an answer and ill mark it as the solution

Comment: @Trr1ppy I would imagine so, I didn't really use the internet much for learning to code when I was in college. The problem with being new and StackOverflow is that it is hard to even know what to ask because you can't know what you don't know. Then, when you're a pro all of the questions seem really obvious. Then all of the new people feel bad about getting down votes from pros thinking its obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code `if(Console.KeyAvailable == true)` is never found to be true because in a couple of ticks (very short amount of time) the key is being read making it unavailable `input = (char)Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;`.

As @Hans Passant said "The odds that you can be quick enough to press a key between the `ReadKey()` and the `KeyAvailable` call are miniscule "

Basically `Console.KeyAvailable` shouldn't be in the same method or loop as `Console.ReadKey`.

So if you want to record what key was pressed then read the key from inside your `if` statement like so:

```
            if (Console.KeyAvailable == true)
            {
                Player.KeyPressed = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
                Player.Movement();
            }
```